# Would the weight be reinitialized whenever model.fit() is called

Tags: python, keras, loss

I intended to read 2 videos each training. I wonder would the weights of the model be reinitialized when each time `model.fit()` is called? Or the weights will be saved? The code is as follows.

```
length = len(videos)
num = 2
steps = length // num
for i in range(steps):
    imgs, labels = many_videos_reader(videos, index=i*num, num=num)
    model.fit(img,label, epochs=3, batch_size=1, initial_epoch=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, weights don't reset whenever you call `fit`. They're *updated* whenever you call `fit`. To reset the weights you may call `model.set_weights()` or just create a new model.